# How to normalize or explode a field from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm reading a JSON file; it looks like this.

```
                   type                                           features
0     FeatureCollection  {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '...
1     FeatureCollection  {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '...
2     FeatureCollection  {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '...
3     FeatureCollection  {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '...
4     FeatureCollection  {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'GEO_ID': '...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to explode the column named 'features' but I can't get it working quite right.

I tried the following code, and it does nothing.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\test.json')
print(type(data))

# not working
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

I also tried this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\test.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
    print(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Even after running the second code sample, everything is jammed into the field named 'features'. How can I break out all the data in features into separate columns and push everything into a standardized dataframe?

Comment: Show us the actual file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having access to more data to test, I think you need to use `.json_normalize` and *then* use `pd.concat` on the results, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\test.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

df_features = pd.json_normalize(data, 'features')

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data.drop('features', axis=1)), df_features], axis=1)

df_properties = pd.json_normalize(df['properties'])
df = pd.concat([df.drop('properties', axis=1), df_properties], axis=1)
```